# How to handle a JSON Array POST request with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to create multiple database entries using only one JSON request. 
Each entry consists only of two values, a type (of action) and a time (when the action happened). To get multiple of those into one request, I am using a JSON Array.

This is what my create action in the controller looks like:

```
def create

   respond_to do |format|

   @actions = []
   save_succeeded = true
   params[:action].each do |action|
      new_action = Action.new(type: action.type, time: action.time)
      save_succeeded = false unless new_action.save
      @actions << new_action
    end

    if save_succeeded
      format.json { render json: @actions, status: :created }
    else
      format.json { render json: @actions.errors, status: 501 }
    end
  end
end
```

When I send a post request to the controller (`/actions.json`) like this:

```
[{ "type": 0, "time": 1234567890 },{ "type": 0, "time": 1234567891 }]
```

I get back an empty array `[]` and a status code of `201 Created`.

This means, the `save_succeeded` variable is still true, but the actions did not get added to the array. Furthermore, the actions are not in my database.

What am I doing wrong? What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor the code a bit:

```
def create
   actions = params[:action].inject([]) do |memo, action|
     memo << Action.create!(type: action[:type], time: action[:time])
   end

   render json: @actions, status: :created

   rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e     
     render json: e.message, status: 501
  end
end
```

Couple of notable changes:

- use `create!` and `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` - `create!` will raise a `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` if the save fails. Then, the rescue block will rescue the exception and you can render a nice error message.
- you cannot use `action.time`, because `params` is a Hash, not an object.
- if you want to build an array to render later, you can use [inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject).
- if you would like to have some atomicity to this (either everything is created or nothing!), you can wrap the whole thing in a transaction block.

It's worth mentioning that I haven't tested the code above, but it should give you a direction and (maybe) it will be a drop-in replacement.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It pointed me in a new direction to try out (parameters as a hash) and I implemented a similar solution. However, I still have an almost similar problem as before: I do not get an error message, but a status code of 201 (Created) with an empty array and no added actions. Since this is such a pain to implement, I will most likely go with an implementation that takes only single requests and just have to make a lot of requests. Thank you for your help though!